# Can a method that calls an accessor method be an accessor method

Tags: java, methods, getter, accessor

```
public Class accessor {
    private int x = 0; 

    public int getX() {
        return x; 
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getX() + "";
    }
}
```

Is the method toString() an accessor method in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Accessor, a.k.a getter, as the name suggests is used to directly access a property of the class. `toString` is normal public method that performs some logic (more than just returning directly the value of certain field). Usually such method is overriden to provide a string representation of the internal state of the object.

Answer (score 0):

`toString` is not considered an accessor since it doesn’t access an attribute (property) of the object, but rather the object as a whole (though I do see your point).

Accessors are getters (usually named `getSomething`, or `isSomething` for `boolean`s) and setters (usually named `setSomething`).

To answer the question in your title too, there is nothing wrong with one accessor calling another accessor. I believe this happens regularly (even though not in your example).

In a class representing persons you might for example have a getter for full name calling the getters for first and last name:

```
    public String getFullName() {
        return getFirstName() + ' ' + getLastName();
    }
```

I would regard `getFullName` as an accessor since we may regard the full name as a property of the person (and its name starts with `get`) .

Comment: but i think he is interested, can we call one method calling another accessor as accessor?

Comment: Thx for the comment, @TheScientificMethod. I have added a code example to clarify the point you are mentioning. Hope it helps?